# Uploading duplicate images from camera roll in swift 3,4

Tags: ios, swift

I've been using this **DKImagePickerController** for a year now and up until recently, multiple images that I attempt to upload to my app from the camera roll are showing up in duplicates of one of the images. ie. I chooses three images from my album, the third image is uploaded three times. I have debugged extensively and used different methods to access the data of the images. I used version 3.8.1 on both swift 3.2 and 4 and your latest beta version.
I'll be details as I can on what I used on separate testings sessions
swift 3.2 and 4, DK version 4.0.0 beta2

```
let documentDirectory = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

for (i, asset) in assets.enumerated {
    let imageName = "tapan\(i).png"
    self.imgPathUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
   //loop header is the same for the rest
   asset.fetchOriginalImage(completeBlock: { (image, info) in
      let newImg = self.resizeImage(image!, newWidth: self.view.frame.width) //changes size
      let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImg, 1)

      do{
        try jpegData?.write(to: self.imgPathUrl, options: .atomic)
      }catch{
         print("Write image to url failed ")
      }

      self.arrSelectedGalleryMedia.add(self.imgPathUrl)
      if self.arrSelectedGalleryMedia.count >= assets.count{
          SharedClass.sharedInstance.hideLoader()
           self.addMedia() //add images
          }
    })
 }
```

///on a separate loop

```
asset.fetchImageData(completeBlock: {(data,info) in
     do{
         try data?.write(to: self.imgPathUrl, options: .atomic)
        }catch{
          print("Error\(error)")
        }

       self.arrSelectedGalleryMedia.add(self.imgPathUrl)
       if self.arrSelectedGalleryMedia.count >= assets.count{
            SharedClass.sharedInstance.hideLoader()
            self.addMedia() //add images
       }
 })
```

Swift 3.2 and 4, DK version 3.8.1

`

```
asset.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock({ (image, info) in
  let newImg = self.resizeImage(image!, newWidth: self.view.frame.width)
  let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImg, 1)

  do{
      try jpegData?.write(to: self.imgPathUrl, options: .atomic)
    }catch{
       print("Write image to url failed ")
    }
   self.arrSelectedGalleryMedia.add(self.imgPathUrl)
   if self.arrSelectedGalleryMedia.count >= assets.count{
        SharedClass.sharedInstance.hideLoader()
        self.addMedia() //add images
    }
})
```

`
I used another function in 3.8.1 that write the data to a temporary URL directly and I would store the link in an array.

The issue seems to be coming from **getImageDataManager().fetchImageData**.
Like in the example I mentioned ***I can see the assets have been collected but as I loop through each assets, it skips the first two and loops on the third image three times.***
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: what is the value of imgPathUrl?

Comment: a temporary URL that I would use tho write the image to. I updated the question with the lines of that I used

Answer (score 0):

I used a different library. [TLPhotoPicker](https://github.com/tilltue/TLPhotoPicker). DKImagePicker may need to fix the issue first. I opened a ticket earlier on [github](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/issues/449). Hope they'll have a solution for their library

```
extension addMediaViewController: TLPhotosPickerViewControllerDelegate{
    func dismissPhotoPicker(withTLPHAssets: [TLPHAsset]) {
    }
}
```